# Data Binding for Dynamic View

Tags: android, mvvm, android-databinding

I want to inflate a layout in a loop for creating 8x8 view. How can I apply databinding in this case?

Parent layout is,

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:id="@+id/gridViewBx"
    android:foregroundGravity="center"
    app:columnCount="8"
    app:rowCount="8">
```

And child layout, I need to add in a loop is,

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:padding="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iconImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/white_circle_png"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You can use RecyclerView instead of creating grids in for loop

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following snippet:

```
DataBindingUtil.inflate(getLayoutInflater(), layoutId, gridLayout, true)
```

Where `layoutId` is your child layout and `gridLayout` being your `GridLayout` reference.

Comment: Thanks for response. Do you have any sample code for understanding the layout and view?

Comment: You mean the `GridLayout` view group and the `View` class?

Comment: I mean the view and model class